# How to pass the parameters for switch controller to server in swift programmatically?

Tags: ios, swift, uiswitch

```
let url = NSURL(string: urlString)

let theRequest = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: url!)

theRequest.HTTPMethod = "POST"

let parameters = ["userId":userId.text!,"status":"offline"] as Dictionary<String,String>


var err:NSError!

do{

    theRequest.HTTPBody = try NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(parameters, options: [])
}

catch let error as NSError
{
    err = error
    theRequest.HTTPBody = nil
}

theRequest.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
theRequest.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")
```

How to pass the parameter for switch control to server?

Comment: what do u mean param for switch control? unclear question

Comment: I mean the format to send request to server for switch Controller. @Tj3n

Comment: Is it Bool? u mean true and false right?

Comment: 1. No need to cast the parameters as a dictionary of type String:String. Swift can infer this. 2. You have 2 "theRequest.addValue." The first one should be ".setValue" instead.

Comment: Is that the issue? @joey

Comment: see my answer below, and test the status code. the HTTP status code you will receive will give you a better indication of what the problem is. It could be multiple problems.

Answer (score 0):

to pass the value of the bool, you need to pass it as another parameter into the function. for example, right now you have:

```
let url = NSURL(string: urlString)
```

change it to:

```
 let url = NSURL(string: urlString, value1: Bool)
```

then, when you call this post function from your view controller, you need to get the current state of the bool value that corresponds to the value of the switch. You can do that like so:

```
let value = yourBool.boolValue()
```

then, in your post function, do something like this:

```
  let url = NSURL(string: urlString, value1: Bool)
  var status = String()
  if value1 == true {
  status = "online"
  }
  else {

  status = "offline"

  }

 let theRequest = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: url!)

 let parameters = ["userId":userId.text!,"status":status]
```

Comment: Just need to know the format of passing the switch controller(true or false).. My server is working fine.

Comment: ahh. do you mean the "status" part of the parameters? like offline or online?

Comment: ok I changed my answer. You will need to connect a bool in your view controller to change value depending on the on/off state of the switch. this is the bool value to be passed. I hope my answer clears things up.

Comment: But there is an unresolved identifier yourBool. Where we have to declare that? and also value @joey

Comment: those are values that you have to declare in your view controller. I assume that this post function is located in an NSObject class, and that you are calling the function from your view controller. maybe post all relevant code--view controller class and the class you make your post request from.